# Importing iCalendar events with alarms into Outlook 2007

Tags: outlook-2007, icalendar

I've written an iCalendar export for various events in my company's web application, and Outlook is able to import the events without error. However, it seems that alarms only get imported when I import a single event, not when there are multiple events in the calendar.

Is this a "feature" of Outlook 2007, or might my multi-event calendars have some characteristic that prevents Outlook from importing these alarms properly?

Here is my single event calendar:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//PYVOBJECT//NONSGML Version 1//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20000101T000000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=1
TZNAME:EST
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:assigned-vevent-796-685089@xxx.xxx
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20100224T124500
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20100224T124500
DESCRIPTION:I hope so.
DTSTAMP:20100211T164751Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY:Does outlook import alarms?
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:I hope so.
TRIGGER:-PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

And my two event calendar:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//PYVOBJECT//NONSGML Version 1//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20000101T000000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=1
TZNAME:EST
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:assigned-vevent-792-685089@xxx.xxx
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20100209T165500
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20100209T165500
DESCRIPTION:I am happy in february.
DTSTAMP:20100209T195442Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:3
SUMMARY:happy february!
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:I am happy in february.
TRIGGER:-PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:assigned-vevent-796-685089@xxx.xxx
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20100224T124500
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20100224T124500
DESCRIPTION:I hope so.
DTSTAMP:20100211T164751Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY:Does outlook import alarms?
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:I hope so.
TRIGGER:-PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have noticed in Outlook 2007 is that any .ics file that is not imported into the Default user calendar will not show alarms (when you double click an ics file it will go to a fresh calendar, not showing alarms).
It works if you go to File>Import/Export>Import vCalendar and choose Import on the prompt that asks if you want to create a new calendar or import into the existing one.